# how do i implement a notification system after new inserts in my db?

Tags: php, mysql, insert, cron

I am working on a web application in php. 
I have a local job listing website. I am working on a scraper in simple html dom that scrapes all the active job listings on the website.

The job listings have a "posted on" date and a "closing" date ( on reaching closing date, the listing is removed from the website).

i have managed to successfully scrape all the active listings on the website and save them in a simple mysql database. The current active job listing is 325 jobs. I have all of them on my DB.

The next thing i have done , is set up cron, so as the scraper runs every hours.

what i basically want is, how should i procede with the Insert in the mysql DB, currently, every times the scraper runs, it deletes all listings and inserts all listings again including a new one.

Eventually i need to set something like a notification system, as soon as a new job is posted - an email notification will be sent to an email address.

what is the best way to procede?I am out of ideas currently..

Comment: Don't replace all the data in your table. Set a cron job that checks expired records and deletes them. You just add new data in the table. Doing that, check for duplicates. There's a chance that a job you already have in your table might have extended its expiration date, or some details in its description.

Comment: @inhan this seems to be a good idea, to have a cron job that checks for expired records. But how can i proceed with the notification system, that will email me as soon as a new listing is added?

Comment: Just save the time (as datetime) that specific cron job executes, so in its next execution it will look for jobs with insertion time > last saved time. If it catches anything, the script can use the `mail()` function to notify you with necessary (new record) data. You need to update this time each time this script is run, of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can use triggers. Set a trigger AFTER every INSERT.
More on triggers here. 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: AFAIK, a trigger is not capable of doing anything outside its scope, that is the database(s). How would this help the OP?

Comment: Trigger is confined to a database you cannot use out of this scope, Definitely you have to create  a cron job.http://net.tutsplus.com/?s=cron+job